# Adding offset and fetch next to SQL query which returns json_object_t array of records throws error

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use offset and fetch next clause in my below SQL query but it is throwing error

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Please help me - how can I use `offset` and `fetch next` clause in this query here, while retaining the response format:

```
DECLARE
    l_json_object JSON_OBJECT_T;
    l_json CLOB;
BEGIN
   SELECT
      JSON_OBJECT(
         KEY 'employees' VALUE 
            JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(KEY 'empno' VALUE id
                           ,KEY 'ename' VALUE name
                           ,KEY 'job' VALUE email_id)
               ORDER BY id
           RETURNING CLOB) 
        RETURNING CLOB)
     INTO l_json
     FROM employee_tbl
    ORDER BY
        id DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
   -- now convert clob to JSON_OBJECT_T
   l_json_object := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE(l_json);
   -- or...this works too
   -- l_json_object := JSON_OBJECT_T(l_json);

   -- check if value is correct
   dbms_output.put_line(l_json_object.to_clob);
END;
/
```

Table sample:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_tbl 
(
    id, 
    name, 
    email_id
) AS
  SELECT 1065, 'Abu',  'email1@example.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1066, 'Umar', 'email2@example.com' FROM DUAL
```

Output expected:

```
{
    "employees":
        [
            { "empno": 1065,"ename": "Abu", "job": "email1@example.com" },
            { "empno": 1066, "ename": "Umar", "job": "email2@example.com" }
        ]
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do - only get the last five employees in the JSON array instead of all of them?

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't from the row limiting clause, it is because you are referencing  the `id` column in the `ORDER BY`. The query is aggregating via `JSON_ARRAYAGG`, so the normal rules about all columns referenced either having to be aggregated or in the `GROUP BY` clause apply. The `id` column isn't either, so you get that error. (You don't have, or want, a `GROUP BY` clause here, but one is implied.)

(But slightly confusingly, if you *only* have the `ORDER BY` then it would not error - though arguably it should - and adding the row limiting clause does then error, which might be why you thought it was that clause causing the problem; but row limiting on its own doesn't error... You can see that [in this simple fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1fiid3nK).)

However, you are selecting a single value into a scalar variable, so row limiting (offset/fetch) and ordering doesn't make sense here anyway. You can only ever get one CLOB value back.

Assuming you are trying to only get the last five employees (by ID) in the JSON array you can filter the table results first, before converting to JSON.

Instead of:

```
     INTO l_json
     FROM employee_tbl
    ORDER BY
        id DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

you can use a subquery (inline view) that limits the rows from the base table:

```
     FROM (
         SELECT id, name, email_id
         FROM employee_tbl
         ORDER BY id DESC
         OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
     );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fttgO6ue)